# Observer recently opened documents and apps in Mac

Tags: macos, cocoa, mono, applescript

I am trying to write a small app that monitors the recently used documents and apps for Mac.
I found the `[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]`. But I can't figure out which selector I should listen to.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the recent items yourself, out of the property list file at Library/Preferences/com.apple.recentitems.plist. You could even observe that directory with FSEvents and note whenever the file changed and re-read it to get the changes...

BUT, unfortunately, this file is only updated rarely (like, when you log out) so it’s not going to change while your app is running as the user opens new documents.